# has_one and belongs_to together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, database-normalization

At first glance, this may look like a simple question. You may even suspect it's been answered before, but not *quite*. I've done a good deal of scouring the web (including stack overflow) and have been unable to find an answer.

This is the closest thing I could find: [Using has_one and belongs_to together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392434/using-has-one-and-belongs-to-together) however it doesn't quite answer my question.

I'm using Rails 4 and MySQL

The database structure is as follows:

partners table

```
id
name
primary_contact_id
```

contacts table

```
id
partner_id
first_name
last_name
```

Pretty straight forward, right? Self explanatory.

```
class Partner < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_one :primary_contact, :class_name => "Partners::Contact", :primary_key => 'primary_contact_id'

    has_many :contacts, :class_name => "Partners::Contact"

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :primary_contact

    validates_presence_of :primary_contact

end

class Partners::Contact < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :partner

end
```

As you can see, when creating a partner, a primary contact is required (the forms etc are all set up properly)

The only issue I'm experiencing is that when the primary_contact is created along with the partner, ActiveRecord doesn't understand that it needs to assign the partner_id on the contact that is getting created, to the partner_id that is being created...

Best practices here? I don't want to create a column in the contacts table that indicates (bool or otherwise) if that contact is primary or not. That's not proper database normalization (regardless of what "rails convention" touts).

Thanks for your help and thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're creating partner in a way similar to this:

```
Partner.create params[:partner] # { ..., primary_contact: {} }
```

So there is no way rails can know that you are creating contact here. One simple solution without adjusting schema would be to use additional query to normalize data:

```
class Partner
  after_create :update_primary_contact

  def update_primary_contact
    self.contacts << self.primary_contact
  end
end
```

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I just tried it, however due to the way that the partner is created params.require(:partner).permit(:company_name, ... primary_contact_attributes: ...) My tests are still failing...